# How should I start Factoring this?

Tags: factoring

So im supposted to factor this and I'm not sure where to start, where should I start?
$$2x^5 + 3x^4 -10x^3 -15x^2 + 8x + 12$$

Comment: Are you sure this is the right polynomial?

Comment: The current one that is up is the correct one.

Comment: $1$ seems to be a solution.

Comment: @Kyle: then $1$ and $-1$ are fairly obviously solutions.

Comment: Indeed, so a hefty dose of synthetic division until you've split off enough linear factors to be left with a quadratic (it does factor completely) or, if super lucky, a nicely-factorable cubic.

Comment: Rational root theorem is the key to factoring most of these types of problems.

Answer (score 2):

Note, for $f(x)=2x^5+3x^4−10x^3−15x^2+8x+12$, $$f(1)=f(-1)=f(2)=f(-2)=f(-\frac{3}{2})=0$$

Using synthetic divisions with $1$ and $-1$, you get that $$f(x)=(x+1)(x-1)(2x^3+3x^2-8x-12)$$

You can use the other roots to further factor the degree-3 polynomial.

Comment: Why bother doing synthetic division once you've identified all five roots?  It would suffice to say that $f$ must be the product of $x-1$, $x+1$, $x-2$, $x+2$, and $2x+1$.

Comment: Indeed, synthetic division after finding all roots is unnecessary. I just wanted to give OP a roadmap of where he would be when he reaches the degree-3 polynomial during his full solution, since he asked for where to start factoring, and not simply the final terms.

Comment: The last root should be $-\frac{3}{2}$, not $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @DerekLedbetter you're right! Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To approach this sort of problem, I usually proceed in one of two ways:

- The brutal approach: pose $P(x) = \prod_i (x - \alpha_i)$ and find all $\alpha_i$ at once. Note: you have to adapt this approach when the highest-order coefficient is not one.
- The fine approach: I try to check if any integer, most notably 1, -1 or 2, -2 are roots of the polynomial. If they are, then I would factorize accordingly.

In your case, 1 is a root, and so is -1. So you can start looking for a new degree-3 polynomial $Q(x)$ that satisfies $P(x) = (x-1)(x+1)Q(x)$

Then, try to the factor the rest.